# How to make Facebook Post to a Page public using the Graph API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a post to a **Facebook Page** and got the `permalink_url` successfully using the api as shown in my code below:

```
let postUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/${pageId}/feed`;
let { data } = await axios.post(postUrl, urlParams);
let postId = data.id;

let accessToken = access_token;
let postLinkRequestUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/${postId}?fields=permalink_url&access_token=${accessToken}`;

let postLinkRequestResponse = await axios.get(postLinkRequestUrl);
let { permalink_url } = postLinkRequestResponse.data; //Perma Link gotten successfully for post to be rendered outside Facebook
```

Now, I'm trying to render the post outside Facebook using a ReactJS Library called `react-facebook` as below

```
<FacebookProvider appId={process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_APP_ID}>
     <EmbeddedPost href={post.permaLink} 
                   width="200" 
                   onLoad={() => {
                    setLoaded(true);
                }} />
</FacebookProvider>
```

And all I keep getting back in return is this error message

> This Facebook post is no longer available. It may have been removed or the privacy settings of the post may have changed.

Which begs the question, how can I make the post public during the creation phase or what else can I do so I can render it outside Facebook even though it is within a specific Facebook Page.

Thanks in anticipation of your response.

Comment: Is the app approved?

Comment: @WizKid The app is still in development

Comment: Posts made by an app in development mode are only visible to people with a role in the app, and can not be embedded using the plugin.

Comment: @CBroe I see. Does that mean, if the app eventually goes live I can now display it outside using the plugin, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work then.